# JMeter use variable array values individually

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am struggling a bit to make use of a variable created using the Json extractor, I have extracted all the ID's from a response and want to cycle through them individually across the threads.

Thread 1 would use id_1 and thread 2 would use id_2 etc.

I have tried using a ForEach controller but it's cycling through the whole set for each thread.

Test runs like this:

1. Generate access token
2. Get parameters - Extract the list of ID's here.
3. Update parameter - Pass the ID individually here per thread.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this because as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if you want to perform extraction using one thread and then hit everything using multiple threads you can either convert all the variables which start with `id_` to JMeter Properties using the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) snippet:

```
vars.entrySet().each { variable ->
    if (variable.getKey().startsWith('id_')) {
        props.put(variable.getKey(), variable.getValue())
    }
}
```

[image]

and then you will be able to access the properties using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(id_${__threadNum},)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, this has resolved my issue and will make my test much more flexible. I am new to JMeter so still learning.